# Inconsistent Results in TensorFlow/Keras Training on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, dask, random-seed

I have a Python code (parallelized with dask) that trains multiple neural networks on a Kubernetes cluster. I want deterministic results, and therefore seed each worker before training the neural networks. The issue I'm facing becomes apparent when I provide all workers with the same seed, since in this case they should all produce identical results. However, some workers end up generating different results.

Example Output:

```
Worker 0:  Seed 0: result:: -2.4244613650037827 <-- running on Node A
Worker 1:  Seed 0: result:: -2.4244613650037827 <-- running on Node A
Worker 2:  Seed 0: result:: -2.4259607599960265 <-- running on Node X **
Worker 3:  Seed 0: result:: -2.4259607599960265 <-- running on Node Y **
Worker 4:  Seed 0: result:: -2.4259607599960265 <-- running on Node X **
Worker 5:  Seed 0: result:: -2.4244613650037827 <-- running on Node B
Worker 6:  Seed 0: result:: -2.4244613650037827 <-- running on Node B
Worker 7:  Seed 0: result:: -2.4244613650037827 <-- running on Node A
Worker 8:  Seed 0: result:: -2.4244613650037827 <-- running on Node C
Worker 9:  Seed 0: result:: -2.4244613650037827 <-- running on Node A
Worker 10: Seed 0: result:: -2.4244613650037827 <-- running on Node A
Worker 11: Seed 0: result:: -2.4244613650037827 <-- running on Node A
Worker 12: Seed 0: result:: -2.4244613650037827 <-- running on Node A
Worker 13: Seed 0: result:: -2.4259607599960265 <-- running on Node Y **
```

The workers producing different results are running on the same nodes (in the example above nodes X and Y). Note that these workers produce identical results among themselves (i.e. pods running on nodes X and Y produce the same result, but different from those running on nodes A, B and C).

The code uses CPUs, and no GPUs are involved. I've tried to identify any potential differences between the processor types or architecture used on nodes X and Y compared to A, B and C, but haven't been able to identify any differences.

**Additional information**
I've verified that the data for all workers is equivalent just before creating and training the neural networks.
The random operations with NumPy and scikit-learn before initializing neural networks are consistent among workers.
I am setting seeds for TensorFlow and Keras using tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(seed).
Despite running on CPUs, I've set tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism().

**Environment:**
Python 3.9
TensorFlow 2.10.0 (with Keras backend)

**Question:**
Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and what steps can I take to ensure consistent results among workers, especially when running on Kubernetes with CPU-only configurations?

Comment: Have you checked that all workers are using the same environment (i.e. versions of dependencies are exactly the same)?

Comment: All the workers are running in pods using the same Docker image (with all the python modules installed in a Poetry environment), so as far as I can tell that implies that the environment is exactly the same...

Comment: Update: I've checked the python environments now, and the workers that are getting different results are using the exact same versions of all python packages

Comment: Note: The results are reproducible when using tensorflow version 2.4.1 (which, however, not an option for me because I need compatibility with python 3.9). I've also tried with tensorflow 2.15.0, which (like 2.10.0) is giving irreproducible results.

Comment: Update: I've resolved the issue for now by changing to tensorflow 2.8.0, which (like 2.4.1) is giving reproducible results - I've tested this by running simultaneously with 2.15 and 2.8, and workers running on the nodes which are giving "bad" results when using 2.15 are giving "good" results (i.e. the same as all other workers) when using 2.8. 
This solution will work for now, but I'd still very much like to understand why tensorflow 2.10, 2.11 and 2.15 are giving inconsistent results when running on a Kubernetes cluster, since I have to update again at some point in the future.

Comment: Without a MRE, it will be tough to identify the source of inconsistency...